# Serilog remove $type property

Tags: .net, serilog

I have following logger configuration

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
  .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"))
  .WriteTo.Console(new CompactJsonFormatter())
  .Destructure.UsingAttributes()
  .Enrich.WithProperty("CorrelationIdHeader", "someId")
  .CreateLogger()
```

I'm executing:

```
logger.Information("{@MyObject}", new MyObject {SomeVal = ""});
```

Console output json always contains $type property, which I would like to remove

```
{
  ...
  "$type": "MyObject"
}
```

How would I remove $type during configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to construct the `CompactJsonFormatter` with a `JsonValueFormatter` that doesn't output the type. You can do that by specifying `null` as the `typeTagName` when creating the `JsonValueFormatter`:

```
new CompactJsonFormatter(new JsonValueFormatter(null))
```

Comment: Thank you, you've saved me a lot of time!